# Regex to find minimum 3 characters followed by a dot and white space

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a regex to identify a pattern in which there is a word of minimum 3 characters followed by a dot and then a white space.

For example in the following sentence:

```
In the movie, Astaire sings the song to Rogers as they dance. The song was nominated for the Best Song Oscar for 1936
```

I would like to find the ". " that ends "Rogers as they dance. "

In the following sentences I don't want to get a match:

```
The Letters of T. S. Eliot and a facsimile of the draft of The Waste Land

There are two Dr. Who feature films: Dr. Who and the Daleks
```

Is there a regex expression that will achieve these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
.*\w{3,}\.\s.*
```

Comment: Thanks, but please note that these sentences are just examples.

Comment: Please re check the edit

Comment: he wanted to match just the period, not the whole sentence. try using lookarounds

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I've upvoted to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are searching for something that you can separate the `word` and the `dot`. so I wrote a regex for this problem , hope to be helpful:

```
(?<word>\\w{3,})(?<dot>\\.)\s
```

**Explanation**

as you are coding in java (one of your tags) I think you should use `"\\"` instead of `"\"`. and for making easy to grouping the separations, I named the groups to `word` and  `dot`.

Comment: If you want to show us what a string literal looks like with double escaped sequences then you should surround it with quote marks just like a Java string literal

Comment: @PatrickParker thanks for advice, at the first I had a struggle with this problem, i will modify this again